# A word to describe somebody with smartphone-only tech skills

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests, technology

I'm stuck finding a word to use for somebody who thinks he has tech skills because he can use the latest trendy mobile apps, though in fact he knows nothing about technology (e.g. how an app is made: how to create it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283385/whats-the-word-for-someone-that-doesnt-know-something-but-pretend-to-know-it   and   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288013/what-is-a-word-or-phrase-for-someone-who-professes-to-know-something-but-actuall

Comment: Well in my opinion not exactly a duplicate as I mean something specific to technology. Somebody who just cares about the superficial hype but not the concrete thing.

Comment: The pretending aspect suggests ***poser***, but I don't have a word that connotes technology specifically. Hackers will denigrate ***script kiddies***, so perhaps you could create a new term for ***app kiddies***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person who knows how to use a fancy state-of-the-art app with great ease and familiarity is just a [competent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/competent) "**user**", they are not a developer or programmer.

> A **[user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_(computing))** (computing) is a person who uses a computer or network service. Users generally use a system or a software product without the technical expertise required to fully understand it. (Wikipedia)

I might refer to this person as a  "**non-nerd**" but I admit I don't know if this was a commonly-used expression, it makes sense though.

Answer (score 0):

If the person's skills with the apps that they use are significantly above average, I would described the person as a [**power user**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_user) of those apps.